# Error in syntax in PREPARE statement MYSQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, prepare

I've got a problem with my MYSQL script. When i try to execute it, MYSQL Workbench send me info that ive got problem with syntax near "int" . Any ideas?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sprzedaz;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS odwrocenie;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sprzedaz
(Towar VARCHAR(30), Miesiac VARCHAR(20), Wartosc INT);

INSERT INTO Sprzedaz VALUES('Buty', 'styczen', 230);
INSERT INTO Sprzedaz VALUES('Buty', 'styczen', 100);
INSERT INTO Sprzedaz VALUES('Koszula', 'styczen', 50);
INSERT INTO Sprzedaz VALUES('Koszula', 'luty', 80);
INSERT INTO Sprzedaz VALUES('Krawat', 'marzec', 190);

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE odwrocenie()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE miesiac_var VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE miesiac_kursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Miesiac FROM Sprzedaz GROUP BY Miesiac;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN miesiac_kursor;
read_loop: LOOP 
    FETCH miesiac_kursor INTO miesiac_var;
  IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    PREPARE sql_query FROM 'ALTER TABLE Sprzedaz ADD COLUMN ? INT';
  EXECUTE sql_query USING @miesiac_var;

END LOOP;
CLOSE miesiac_kursor;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE sql_query;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

    CALL odwrocenie();
```

Comment: `DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE`? shouldn't it be `DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0`?

Comment: Its nevermind ;/ Not solving the problem.

Comment: Do you know which line? If not, have you tried commenting out part of the code to narrow it down?

Comment: Yes the problem is in PREPARE statement. W/o it it's working.

Comment: "?" is for data values only, not for "everything". https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/prepare.html

Comment: So there is no way to do such a thing ? No way...

Comment: Dont think so. When i use @set = myquery + miesiac + type; and prepare it and execute its stil the same problem. And notice, that i dont use '?' even once then.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687803/mysql-variables-in-alter-table-script

Comment: Man u are my hero. I dont know why it's working while mine solutin dont but still THANKS!

Comment: You cannot treat a column name as a parameter.  You have to build it into the query string.