# Expression for set AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I try set `AUTO_INCREMENT` for table with `count()` result.
When I try get:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 from `Lista`;
```

I've got:

```sql
|COUNT(*) + 1|
+------------+
|6           |
```

I'ts Ok.
When I try:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT = 6;
```

I'ts Ok - new row has `id = 6`;
But when I try use this code:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 from `Lista`);
```

I've got this error:

> (1064): Syntax error near '(SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 from Lista)' at line 2

I tried use variables, but in this case:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 INTO @old_auto_inc FROM `Lista`;
ALTER TABLE `tmp` AUTO_INCREMENT = @old_auto_inc;
```

I've got:

> (1064): Syntax error near '@old_auto_inc' at line 2

How I can set `AUTO_INCREMENT` with expression result?

```sql
|@@version          |
+-------------------+
|5.6.29-1~dotdeb+7.1|
```

**Update**
I tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11688061/3335966):

```sql
SELECT max(id) + 1 INTO @inc FROM Lista;
set @st = 'ALTER TABLE tmp AUTO_INCREMENT = ?';
PREPARE stmt FROM @st;
EXECUTE stmt USING @inc;
```

But I've got error:

> (1064): Syntax error near '?' at line 1

Comment: Set it to a value and be done with it. You are not going to have happy results if you think count(*) has much to do with it or that is safe. And it sure wouldn't be count anyway. It would be `max()`

Comment: I just confirmed that the duplicate reference (sole answer) will work with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` set.

Comment: @Drew I tried marked solution, but I still get error;

Comment: show what you tried in an [edit] or pastebin, and show the error. *It didn't work* don't cut it :p

Comment: But like I said in the first comment, set and forget. Peeps have no business resetting that value unless they are pro's and know what they are doing. In which case they don't need to ask peons like me

Comment: @Drew sorry, Your English too hard for my "non English speaker" understanding =( But I learned a few new slang words =)